# Adoption of TDD on older Java application

Tags: java, testing, web-applications

I've got a problem and I'm asking you for help

I've started working on web application, that has no tests, is based on spring 2.5 and hibernate 3.2, is not very well modularized, with classes having up to 5k lines, as view technology there is JSP used all over the place with quite a lot things duplicated (like many similar search forms with very few differencies but with not many shared parts).

Aplication works well, however, everything is running just fine, but when there is need to add or to change some functionality, it is realy slow and not very convenient.

Is there any possibility to employ TDD at this point? Or what would you recomend as I dont't think I can develop it forever the way it is now, it is just getting messier all the time.

Thanky you for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by picking up a copy of Michael Feathers' book [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) - this is pure gold.

Once you learn techniques for refactoring and breaking apart your application at it's logical seams, you can work on integrating TDD in newer modules/sprout classes and methods, etc.

Case in point, we recently switched to a TDD approach for a ten year old application written in almost every version of our framework, and while we're still struggling with some pieces, we've made sure that all of our new work is abstracted out, and all of the new code is under test.

So absolutely doable - just a bit more challenging, and the book above can be a tremendous help in getting started.

Comment: Also - as noted in another answer, if you hit huge black boxes - start with an integration test first before digging into the refactoring so you at least have a safety net.

Comment: Absolutely grab this old, but great, book. It describes exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I agree. Working Effectively with Legacy Code will provide you with a variety of techniques for getting an application like this tamed and under test a little bit at a time. It's an absolute must-read for any developer.

Answer (score 3):

First, welcome to the club of poor good programmers that have to fix crimes done by their worse colleagues. :(

I had such experience. In this case one of the recommended practices is developing tests for new features. You cannot stop now and develop tests for whole application. What you can do is every time you have to write new feature develop tests for this feature also. If this feature requires changes in some sensitive places start tests for these places.

Refactoring is a big problem. Ideally if you want to separate 5k lines class to 10 normal size classes you should first develop test case(s) for the big class, then perform refatoring and then run tests again to validate that you have not break anything. It is very hard in practice because when you change the design you change the interface and therefore you cannot run exactly the same tests. So, each time you should make the hard decision what is the best way and what are the minimal test case that covers your ass.

For example sometimes I performed 5 phase refatoring:
1. developed tests for bad big class
2. developed new well designed code and changed the old class to be the facade for my new code. 
3. ran the test case developed in #1 to validate that everything works
4. developed new tests that verify that each new (small) sub module works well
5. refactred code, i.e. removed all references to the big old class (that became lightweight facade)
5. removed the old class and its tests.

But this is the worse case scenario. I had to use it when code that I am changing is extremely sensitive.

Shortly, good luck in your hard job. Prepare to work overnight and then receive 20 bug reports from QA and angry email from your boss. :( Be strong. You are on the right way!

Comment: If you need to change the test when you change the implementation then it is not refactoring, it's just change.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel like you can't make any changes for fear of breaking stuff, then you have answered your own question: you need to do something.

The first rule of holes is: If you are stuck in a hole, stop digging.

You need to institute a policy such that if code is committed without a test, that is the exception and not the rule.   Use continuous integration and force people to keep the build passing.

I recommend starting by capturing the core functionality of the app in tests, both unit and integration.  These tests should be a baseline that shows the necessary functionality is working.

You mentioned there is a lot of code duplication.  Thats the next place to go.  Put a test around an area with duplicate code.  You will be testing 2 or more items here, since there is duplication.  Then do a refactor and see if the tests still pass.

Once you knock one domino down, the rest will follow.

Comment: "no new code gets written without tests" is utterly impractical. No commercial project can afford the luxury of stopping all new development for months while they refactor everything to make that possible.

Comment: "No new code gets written without tests" does not imply that the entire codebase must be retrofitted with tests. It means that in your little area, you write tests for all new code. Rather than wedging more code into a 5kloc class, write a separate class, test that and call it from the old code.

Comment: @James, yes "extract method and characterise"

Comment: @James: that's all very nice in theory. In practice, that separate class usually ends up with impossible-to-mock dependencies all over the place and simply cannot be meaningfully tested on its own.

Comment: @Michael - Sometimes it takes some creativity, but it is possible. Believe me I've done it. Sometimes you need wrappers around existing classes so that your new class is isolated and its dependencies mockable. It's all about creating seams in your old code where you can start building new and tested code.

Comment: @michael, there are 2 options. Either they start testing, which is going to take (more) time than usual because of the technical debt they have incurred, or they are not going to test, and have a huge amount of risk with making changes.  The OP did not mention that new releases are getting deployed every week, if he has a reasonable schedule, he can certainly do testing.

Comment: @hvgotcodes: there is a big difference between "start testing" and "no new code gets written without tests" - some parts of such an app will be completely intractable to testing, and the effort it takes to make them testable could be much more productive elsewhere. All I'm saying is that you should concentrate your testing efforts where you gain most from them - and that's not necessarily all new code.

Comment: @michael, fair enough.  But committing code without tests should be the exception and not the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is definitely a place for TDD, but it is only a part of the solution.

You need to `refactor` this application before you can make any changes. Refactoring requires test coverage to be in place. Take small portions of obviously substandard code and write `characterisation` tests for them. This means you test all the variations possible through that code. You will probably find bugs doing this. Raise the bugs via your QA system and keep the buggy behaviour for now (lock the bugs in with your characterisation tests as other parts of the system might, for now, be relying on the buggy behaviour).

If you have very long and complex methods, you may call upon your IDE to extract small portions to separate methods where appropriate. Then write characterisation tests for those methods. Attack big methods in this way, bit by bit, until they are well-partitioned. Finally, once you have tests in place, you can refactor.

`integration` tests can be useful in this circumstance to highlight happy-day scenarios or a few major error scenarios. But usually in this circumstance the application is far too complex to write a complete integration test suite. This means you might never be protected 100% against side-effects using integration tests alone. That is why I prefer 'extract method' and characterise.

Now that your application is protected from side-effects, you may add new features using TDD.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to start adding tests piece by piece.  If there is a section you know you're going to have to update in the near future, start getting some good coverage on that section.  Then when you need to update/refactor, you have your regression tests.  From the sounds of it, it will be a major undertaking to establish a comprehensive test suite, but it will most likely pay off in the end.  I would also suggest using one of the various code coverage tools available to see how much your tests are actually covering.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do *test driven* development at this point, except if you happen to add functionality that is easy to isolate from the rest of the system (which is unlikely).

However, you can (and should) certainly add *automated tests* of your core functionality. Those are at first not going to be real unit tests in the sense of testing small units of code in isolation, but IMO the importance of those is often overstated. **Integration tests** may not run as fast or help you pinpoint the cause of bugs as quickly, but they still help tremendously in protecting you against side effects of changes. And that's something you really need when you refactor the code to make future changes easier and real unit tests possible.

In general, **go for the low hanging but juicy fruit first**: write tests for parts of the code that can be tested easily, or break easily, or cause the most problems when they break (and where tests are thus most valuable), or ideally all of these together. This gives you real value quickly and helps convince reluctant developers (or managers) that this is a path worth pursuing.

A **continuous build server is a must.** A test suite that people have to remember to run manually to get its benefit means that you're wasting most of its benefit.